# Build a Login / register / forgot password form / page

Tags: atk4

Im wanting to build a a Login / register / forgot password form / page using ATK4. Can you point me to any documentation or a tutorial on this.

Thank You

Comment: It was mentioned that documentation was being built for some of this, please update when you do. TY

Comment: It is being added into one of the tutorials. Login, Register, Forgot passwords are just forms, you just need a bit of logic behind. Eventually there will be better solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Documentation

You can see the steps to allow a [login using basicauth with agiletoolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376352/atk4-what-is-the-procedure-for-setting-up-an-admin-area/7378882#7378882) on another question i answered on stackoverflow and on [agiletoolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/auth) and there is some documentation on the [agiletoolkit tutorial](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/auth) pages

The documentation for sending emails using Tmail.php is also on the [agiletoolkit blog](http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/tmail/)

### Manual Way

The login form itself doesnt exist as a page but is defined inside /atk4/lib/BasicAuth.php

To change this to use the database, you can use SqlAuth instead of BasicAuth which then stores the users information and passwords in the database.

In versions before 4.0.3 there was another class called atk4/lib/DBAuth.php which had the following in the header comment

- Improved version of BasicAuth.
- Login/password retrieved from DB table
- Functionality of password recovery and new user registration is included.

and there was an lib/Auth directory containing the following php files

Form.php
PasswordRecovery.php
SignupProcessor.php

The Form.php seems to just create a login page the same as the one in BasicAuth and the passwordRecovery has logic to send an email / provide a link for the user with a timeout to reset their password.

I also need to build registration/forgot password functionality including emailing the user with a one time key to confirm the email address but not at that point yet so cant provide the code to do it.

My approach will be to copy BasicAuth to my webhome/lib directory, modify the login page that is created in BasicAuth to add links for forgot password and register ( I did wonder is there a reason why login is not a real page but is generated on the fly @romans ?). Then create a separte registration page containing an MVCForm of table "user" to store the details and create a couple of templates to send using atk4/lib/TMail.php.